# Latex twoside format with non linear page numbering

Tags: margins, double-sided

I have the following problem:

I need to make a Latex document, where the first part is numbered with roman numbers and the 2nd part in numbered with Arabic numbers. 
The Arabic numbers should start with 1 again. 
Moreover, I have to add some empty pages which do not add to the page counting in between. 
All this messes up my margins for the `twoside` setup.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, bibliography=totoc, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{caption} 

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

\definecolor{TU_blue}{RGB}{0, 102, 153}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{left}
\fancyhead[RE]{right}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{dummy}
\author{my name}
\date{December 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{Roman} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
\section*{Acknowledgements}
\blindtext
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage


\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\section*{Abstract}
\blindtext
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract German}
\section*{Abstract German}
\blindtext
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-1}\newpage

\tableofcontents 
\newpage


\section*{List of Abbreviations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\markboth{List of Abbreviations}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\begin{acronym}\itemsep0pt
\acro{ABC}{Alphabet}
\end{acronym}
\newpage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\newpage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\newpage

\section{Section 2}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{subsection 2.2}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{subsection 2.3}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{subsection 2.4}
\blindtext[4]
\newpage

\blindtext
\newpage


\end{document}
```

The Title page, Acknowledgements, Abstract, Abstract German should all be on the right side. 
However, they should be numbered without empty pages.

Starting from "Contents" the text should appear on both sides. 
Both sides "List of Tables" and "Introduction" are formated as a left page.

One additional minor question because I confused myself a lot at the moment: 
The first page should be the right page, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE should me more minimalistic.  A lot of packages are not needed in your example.

Please: Ask yourself, what **type of document** to prepare.  This is a different question as **how your document should look like**.

In your MWE you defined a document with two-sided layout.  Two-sided layout is the default for a class like `book`.

Regardless of the class (`article` or `book`) you should prepare a document which is **unambiguous**.  One cannot stress this point too much.  If you prepare a document with a two-sided layout, every page has to have a consecutive pagenumber!  You can decide, to not print out the number, but the number is still in existence, hence the next page is the next higher number.

Quoting from your question:

> The Title page, Acknowledgements, Abstract, Abstract German should all be on the right side.

This leads me to the assumption, that an `article` is not the correct choice.  Instead you should choose a `report` or even a `book`-class.  The standard LaTeX classes, as well as those replacements of KOMA-Script, start a new chapter on a right hand side, which of course could also be identified by its odd page number.

But what do you mean with

> However, they should be numbered without empty pages.

As explained above, you can suppress the page numbers to be printed on otherwise empty pages.  KOMA-Script does that by default.

Or did you mean, that an empty page should not be **counted**?  This would lead to page numbers, which could be even-numbered, even for a right hand page.  Are you sure, you will break all traditions?  I would strongly advise against that!

Again, quoting from your question:

> Starting from "Contents" the text should appear on both sides. Both sides "List of Tables" and "Introduction" are formated as a left page.

I have no clue, what you mean.  Do you describe the result of your LaTeX code?  If so, are you ok with it?

Both standard LaTeX classes (`report` and `book`) as well as those KOMA replacements are able to open new chapters also on a left hand side, if the previous chapter happens to end on a right hand page.  Just insert the class-option `openany` in your `\documentclass` command.  The default for `report`, `scrreprt`, `book` and `scrbook` is to open new chapters on a right handed (odd numbered) page.  Hence, the default option is `openright`.

Again, either option you choose will than treat every chapter throughout the complete in the same way, it treated previous chapters in the document.  That is, no expceptions will be made!  The same rule (either openany or openright) will apply.  And that is a good decision.

> One additional minor question because I confused myself a lot at the moment: The first page should be the right page, am I right?

Yes, you are.  1 happens to be an odd number.  The traditional rule says, in book-printing any odd numbers are right handed pages.

---

I modified your MWE by deleting all unneeded packages.  I added a bibliography database, containing one book and added a `\cite` command in the text as well.  More important, I switched from `article` class to a very mighty `scrbook` from KOMA-Script classes.

As "your" document is now of type book, I upgraded the sectioning commands to be one level higher: `\section` was changed into `\chapter` and so forth.

I added the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands, to automatically switch between roman and arabic pagenumberings and deleted your similar attempts.  `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` are special to the book classes, they are not available in article or report classes (neither LaTeX or KOMA-Script).  But using `\frontmatter` also changes the numbering of \chapter: they won't get a number, but will be incorporated in the table of contents.  Easy-peasy. :-)

Please read the acronym manual carefully about its possibilities.  You can automatically get a list of abbreviations with kind help of makeindex ...

In the end of your document, I added the `\appendix` command, to end the normal document and start the appendencies.  As you can see, this command again changes the treatment of the sectioning commands as `\chapter`.  This time, the chapters won't get numbers, but Letters.

I also added a bibliography by `\printbibliography`.  This assumes, you are working with BibLaTeX and the `biber` binary.  The KOMA-Script class options `liststotoc` and `bibtotoc` make sure, that your list of figures and list of tables as well as your bibliography will be listed in the table of contents.  Again easy-peasy. :-)

I hope, you can life with my assumptions and modifications based on them.  Here is my "improved" MWE.  I don't wont to be rude if I give you the advise: "keep it simple, keep it plain".  Start to write your document.  Don't worry about the layout to much (at least in the beginning of the process).  Be assured, LaTeX will produce high quality documents (from the point of typographic view).

Have fun in writing!  The rest will come step by step.  I am sure.

---

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, openright, liststotoc, twoside]{scrbook}
% \documentclass[11pt, openright, twoside]{book}
% \documentclass[11pt, openany, twoside]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%% Needed for the bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Manual{class:scrguide,
  title =    {{KOMA-Script}},
  author =   {Kohm, Markus},
  month =    May,
  year =     2016,
  url =      {http://www.komascript.de/~mkohm/scrguide.pdf},
  langid =   {ngerman},
  note =     {Bestandteil der Online-Dokumentation von \LaTeX,
                  Datei \texttt{scr\-guide.pdf}},
  keywords =     {manual},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname}

%% Maybe you don't need this in KOMA any more?
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \fancyhf{}
% \fancyhead[LO]{left}
% \fancyhead[RE]{right}
% \fancyfoot[OL]{\thepage}
% \fancyfoot[ER]{\thepage}
% \pagestyle{fancy}

\title{dummy}
\author{my name}
\date{December 2019}

\begin{document}

%% Frontmatter starts the preliminaries and uses roman pagenumbers
\frontmatter

\maketitle

\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\blindtext

\chapter{Abstract}
\section*{German}
\blindtext[4]
\section*{English}
\blindtext[7]

%% Start the table of contents and further lists here
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%% only needed in book.cls.  KOMA class option "liststotoc" add these
%% entries automagically
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoftables
%% only needed in book.cls.  KOMA class option "liststotoc" add these
%% entries automagically
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}

%% New: print the nomenclature/abbreviations here.  See package
%% acroynm handbook (texdoc acronym)!
% \printnomenclature

\chapter{List of Abbreviations}
\begin{acronym}\itemsep0pt
\acro{ABC}{Alphabet}
\end{acronym}


%% Here ends the preliminaries and the normal document starts.  The
%% \mainmatter command switches the page numbers to be arabic.
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext

\chapter{Section 2}
\blindtext[4]
\section{subsection 2.1}
\blindtext[4]
\section{subsection 2.2}
\blindtext[4]
\section{subsection 2.3}
\blindtext[4]
\cite{class:scrguide}
\blindtext[3][2]

\section{subsection 2.4}
\blindtext[4]

%% What should this command be good for?
% \newpage

%% End of the document.  Start the appendencies
\appendix

\chapter{Some Appendix}
\blindtext[6]

\chapter{Next Appendix}

\section{First Subappendix}
\blindtext[4]

\section{Another Subappendix}
\blindtext[7]

%% Finally the bibliography
\printbibliography{}


%% Same as above!
% \newpage


\end{document}
```